# Axios 1.4.0 Interceptors: How to add a Meta Data to a request?

Tags: typescript, axios

I want to **add meta data to a request** with an interceptor.
However, I cannot use the code I found in a few examples:

https://binod.hashnode.dev/axios-interceptor

```
instance.interceptors.request.use(
    function (config) {
        config.metadata = { startTime: new Date() };
        return config;
    },
    function (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
```

I am getting this error:

> Property 'metadata' does not exist on type
> 'InternalAxiosRequestConfig'

[image]

I am using Axios 1.4.0 and Typescript 5.0.4. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You can extend Axios config and use it with interceptors like this (used to measure request duration):

```
import { AxiosError, AxiosInstance, AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse, InternalAxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';

import { getBenchmarkMiliseconds } from 'someBenchmarkingLib';


interface AxiosRequestConfigWithMetadata<T = unknown> extends InternalAxiosRequestConfig<T> {
  metadata?: {
    startTime?: number;
    endTime?: number;
  };
}

interface AxiosResponseWithMetadata<T = unknown, D = unknown> extends AxiosResponse<T, D> {
  config: AxiosRequestConfigWithMetadata<D>;
}
interface AxiosErrorWithMetadata<T = unknown, D = unknown> extends AxiosError<T, D> {
  config: AxiosRequestConfigWithMetadata<D>;
}

export interface AxiosInterceptorProps {
  axiosClient: AxiosInstance;
}

export const addLoggingInterceptors = (props: AxiosInterceptorProps) => {
  props.axiosClient.interceptors.request.use(
    (requestConfig: AxiosRequestConfigWithMetadata) => {
      requestConfig.metadata = requestConfig.metadata || {};
      requestConfig.metadata.startTime = getBenchmarkMiliseconds();
      return requestConfig;
    },
    (error) => {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    },
  );

  props.axiosClient.interceptors.response.use(
    (response: AxiosResponseWithMetadata) => {
      const startTime = response.config.metadata?.startTime;
      // do something here
      return response;
    },
    (error: AxiosErrorWithMetadata) => {
      const startTime = error?.config?.metadata?.startTime;
      // do something here
      return Promise.reject(error);
    },
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The return type has recently changed. I'm not sure if there is a preferred way to do it now but you could extend it by using the [typescript declaration merging feature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)

```js
declare module 'axios' {
  export interface InternalAxiosRequestConfig {
    meta: any;
  }
}
```